# Application.DoEvents() equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, swing

I'm running a program in Java which performs a long process. Obviously this causes the event dispatcher thread to get really busy and so stop responding/updating the UI.

I would like it to update the UI while I'm doing this process (I give some information back to the user while it runs). I realise the proper way of doing this would be to use a swing worker thread, or other multi-threaded solution - but for this case assume I can't complicate it too much.

Now in C# there's a dirty fix called "Application.DoEvents()" which forces the UI to update itself - which gives the result I'm looking for. Is there anything similar in Java? I would just like something quick I can plug into the loop without having to break out the multi-threading.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to do things properly? Even in .NET I would strongly discourage you from using `Application.DoEvents`. Doing things properly is almost always a short-term hit for great long-term benefit.

Comment: The program is long and complicated (and has taken ages) enough as it is. I would like to minimise the sledgehammering if possible.

Comment: How long is this program expected to be maintained? Putting in the effort to structure it correctly *now* will pay dividends over time.

Comment: Its come at the very end of its maintainance cycle and this is a last minute request. I wouldn't normally do something of the sort, but in this case it won't be maintained ever again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I realise the proper way of doing this would be to use a swing worker thread, or other multi-threaded solution - but for this case assume I can't complicate it too much.

Swing worker designed exactly for this kind of tasks. It is the way you should write applications in swing. What do mean by "I can't complicate it too much"?

Comment: Well I'm not that experienced with Java, but every single time I went multithreaded with C# (and tried to update ui components) it always turned into a mess of delegates and other things.

Comment: @Aabela Did you try this article? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: @Aabela: Yes, multi-threading is relatively tricky. But hacky ways of avoiding doing the right thing lead to horribly hard-to-debug scenarios. Don't try to take shortcuts - learn to do things properly.